# Convergence of Integral of a Function that does not converge

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Recently, I thought about the following: Can you say if an integral will or won't converge just by considering the function itself? For example, can an integral converge if the function you're integrating is undefined at one of the limits of integration?

In mathematical notation, what I'm asking is:

Can we say that
$$
\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx
$$
converges, even if the limits
\begin{align}
& \lim_{x \to b}f(x) \\
& \lim_{x \to a}f(x)
\end{align}
do not exist?

I can't recall whether if this is true or false, and haven't been able to found literature about this.

Comment: Take $\int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^{-1/2}\,dx$. What do you observe?

Comment: Thank you! that's sufficient proof. @Fabian